# $A+ \lambda I_5$ is not invertible?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

For every matrix $A \in M_5$ there is a real number $\lambda$ so that the matrix $A+ \lambda I_5$ is not invertible.
I am supposed to say if this is true or not, without any calculations, then give an explanation.. but I just don't know where to start.

Comment: This link may be useful https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\det(A+\lambda I_5)$ is a polynomial of degree $5$ in $\lambda$. Hence, using the intermediate value theorem, this polynomial admits a root in $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 2):

The key point here is that the dimension of $A$ is odd. Hence the corresponding polynomial $  |A -\lambda I|$ has degree five.

Since any polynomial of odd degree has a real root. We may deduce that there is a lambda such that $  |A -\lambda I|=0$.